# audio stops playing after some time even after im using background playing service in flutter justaudio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, just-audio

I'm using the list for storing audios for my Just audio player and also I'm using just audio background but after some times the songs Stop playing when in background and app kind of restarts is it because of I'm using a normal list and not storing those songs in a persistent storage like hive or is it because of os battry optimization and how can i overcome this issue?

here is my playercontroller class

```
class playercontroller {
  StreamController<PlayerState> controller = StreamController();
  // late StreamSubscription<PlayerState> completionSubscription;
  var playlist = [].obs;

  var name = ''.obs;
  var artist = ''.obs;
  var image = ''.obs;
  var link = ''.obs;
  var totalDuration = 0.0.obs;
  var position = 0.0.obs;
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  playercontroller._internal();
  var isplaying = false.obs;
  var isloop = false.obs;
  var isSongLoaded = false.obs;
  var currentTrackIndex = 0;
  var hasCompletionListener = false;

  // var playerstate = 'paused';
  static final playercontroller _instance = playercontroller._internal();

  factory playercontroller() {
    return _instance;
  }

  playSong() async {
    isSongLoaded(false);
    await player.stop();
    print('index here $currentTrackIndex');
    if (currentTrackIndex < playlist.length) {
      name(playlist[currentTrackIndex]['name']);
      artist(playlist[currentTrackIndex]['artist']);
      image(playlist[currentTrackIndex]['image']);
      link(playlist[currentTrackIndex]['url']);
      // await player.setUrl(playlist[currentTrackIndex]['url']);
      try {
        await player.setAudioSource(
          AudioSource.uri(
            Uri.parse(playlist[currentTrackIndex]['url']),
            tag: MediaItem(
              // Specify a unique ID for each media item:
              id: '$currentTrackIndex',
              // Metadata to display in the notification:
              // album: "Album name",
              title: "${playlist[currentTrackIndex]['name']}",
              artist: "${playlist[currentTrackIndex]['artist']}",
              artUri: Uri.parse(playlist[currentTrackIndex]['image']),
            ),
          ),
        );
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        print('here is the err $e');
      }
      player.play();
      player.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
        if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed &&
            !hasCompletionListener) {
          currentTrackIndex++;
          playSong();
          hasCompletionListener = true;
        } else if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.ready) {
          totalDuration(player.duration!.inSeconds.toDouble());
          // hasCompletionListener = false;
        } else if (state.processingState != ProcessingState.completed) {
          hasCompletionListener = false;
        }
      });
    }


    player.positionStream.listen(
      (pos) {
        print('we printing this ${pos.secToTime()}');

        position(pos.inSeconds.toDouble());
      },
    );
    isplaying(true);
    isSongLoaded(true);
  }

  playnext() {
    currentTrackIndex++;
    playSong();
  }

  playprevious() {
    currentTrackIndex--;
    playSong();
  }

  pause() {
    player.pause();
    isplaying(false);
  }

  resume() {
    player.play();
    isplaying(true);
  }

  loop() async {
    player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);
    isloop(true);
  }

  unloop() async {
    player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.off);
    isloop(false);
  }
}
```

here is my android manifest permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:minSdkVersion="30" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Kindly share which package you have used in the `pubspec.yaml` for audio. Also, have you configured and setup all the steps shown in the package read me file?

Comment: im using   just_audio: ^0.9.35  & just_audio_background: ^0.0.1-beta.10 i've done all the steps shown in read me file